# Some wrong about sigsetjmp

Tags: c, linux, signals

I am reading the APUE, Chapter 10. Here is my code.

```
#include "apue.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>

static void sig_usr1(int), sig_alrm(int);
static sigjmp_buf jmpbuf;
static volatile sig_atomic_t canjmp;

int 
main(void)
{
    if(signal(SIGUSR1, sig_usr1) == SIG_ERR)
        err_sys("signal(SIGUSR1) error");
    if(signal(SIGALRM, sig_alrm) == SIG_ERR)
        err_sys("signal(SIGALRM) error");
    //print signal.
    pr_mask("Starting main: ");
    if(sigsetjmp(jmpbuf, 1)) {
        pr_mask("End main: ");
        exit(0);
    }
    canjmp = 1;
    for(;;)
        pause();
}

static void
sig_usr1(int signo)
{
    time_t starttime;

    if(canjmp == 0) {
        return;
    }

    pr_mask("starting sig_usr1: ");
    alarm(3);
    starttime = time(NULL);
    for(;;) 
        if(time(NULL) > starttime + 5)
            break;
    pr_mask("finishing sig_usr1: ");
    canjmp = 0;
    siglongjmp(jmpbuf, 1);
}

static void
sig_alrm(int signo)
{
    pr_mask("in sig_arlm: ");
}

void
pr_mask(const char *str)
{
    sigset_t    sigset;
    int         errno_save;

    errno_save = errno;     /* we can be called by signal handlers */
    if (sigprocmask(0, NULL, &sigset) < 0)
        err_sys("sigprocmask error");

    printf("%s", str);
    if (sigismember(&sigset, SIGUSR1))  printf("SIGUSR1 ");
    if (sigismember(&sigset, SIGALRM))  printf("SIGALRM ");
    /* remaining signals can go here  */

    printf("\n");
    errno = errno_save;
}
```

I thought the output would be like this:

```
Starting main:
starting sig_usr1: SIGUSR1
in sig_alrm: SIGUSR1 SIGALRM
finishing sig_usr1: SIGUSR1
End main:
```

but it seems something wrong, this is my output in fact:

```
Starting main:
starting sig_usr1: 
in sig_alrm: 
finishing sig_usr1: 
End main:
```

that is no signals. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the trouble is probably that you are using `signal()` and not `sigaction()` to set the signal handling.  And `signal()` does not mask any other signals - so there are no signals to show as being blocked.  I modified your code as shown below, to use `signal()` and `sigaction()` depending on whether there are any arguments or not.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef void (*Handler)(int);
static void sig_usr1(int), sig_alrm(int);
static sigjmp_buf jmpbuf;
static volatile sig_atomic_t canjmp;
static void pr_mask(const char *str);

static void err_sys(const char *str)
{
    int errnum = errno;
    fprintf(stderr, "%s (%d: %s)\n", str, errnum, strerror(errnum));
    exit(1);
}

static void set_sigaction(int signum, Handler handler)
{
    struct sigaction nact;
    nact.sa_handler = handler;
    sigfillset(&nact.sa_mask);
    //sigemptyset(&nact.sa_mask);
    nact.sa_flags = 0;
    if (sigaction(signum, &nact, 0) != 0)
        err_sys("Failed to set signal handling");
}

int 
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("PID = %u\n", (unsigned)getpid());
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        if (signal(SIGUSR1, sig_usr1) == SIG_ERR)
            err_sys("signal(SIGUSR1) error");
        if (signal(SIGALRM, sig_alrm) == SIG_ERR)
            err_sys("signal(SIGALRM) error");
    }
    else
    {
        set_sigaction(SIGUSR1, sig_usr1);
        set_sigaction(SIGALRM, sig_alrm);
    }
    //print signal.
    pr_mask("Starting main: ");
    if (sigsetjmp(jmpbuf, 1)) {
        pr_mask("End main: ");
        exit(0);
    }
    canjmp = 1;
    for (;;)
        pause();
}

static void
sig_usr1(int signo)
{
    time_t starttime;

    if (canjmp == 0) {
        return;
    }

    pr_mask("starting sig_usr1: ");
    alarm(3);
    starttime = time(NULL);
    for (;;) 
        if (time(NULL) > starttime + 5)
            break;
    pr_mask("finishing sig_usr1: ");
    canjmp = 0;
    siglongjmp(jmpbuf, 1);
}

static void
sig_alrm(int signo)
{
    pr_mask("in sig_arlm: ");
}

void
pr_mask(const char *str)
{
    sigset_t    sigset;
    int         errno_save;

    errno_save = errno;     /* we can be called by signal handlers */
    if (sigprocmask(0, NULL, &sigset) < 0)
        err_sys("sigprocmask error");

    printf("%s", str);
    if (sigismember(&sigset, SIGUSR1))  printf("SIGUSR1 ");
    if (sigismember(&sigset, SIGALRM))  printf("SIGALRM ");
    /* remaining signals can go here  */

    printf("\n");
    errno = errno_save;
}
```

Running on MacOS X 10.7.2 with current XCode (4.2?), I get (for example):

```
$ ./sigtest
PID = 11066
Starting main: 
starting sig_usr1: SIGUSR1 SIGALRM 
finishing sig_usr1: SIGUSR1 SIGALRM 
in sig_arlm: SIGUSR1 SIGALRM 
End main: 
$ ./sigtest 1
PID = 11067
Starting main: 
starting sig_usr1: SIGUSR1 
in sig_arlm: SIGUSR1 SIGALRM 
finishing sig_usr1: SIGUSR1 
End main: 
$
```

Comment: I tried again, but it seems cause by "apue.h", that is, there is statement of `pr_mask` and definition in some other file, and I redefinition it again in my file, so after I delete `#include "apue.h", everything goes well.`

Comment: Well, I'm glad that solved it for you, though I must confess I'm not sure how the declaration in `"apue.h"` caused problems.  Your definition in the source file matches the declaration in the header, and is going to be used in preference to any other definition.  However, that explains why you did not declare `pr_mask()`.